# How to add a judge if jquery ajax return data is empty?

Tags: jquery

I am new to studying jquery.ajax. I want to paste some data from a.php to b.php.
Here is my code:

a.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {      
var params = "value=" + $('#send').text();   
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'html',            
     data:params,  
     success:function(data){  $("#result").html($(data).html('#aa')); }
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>//sometimes the return data is empty, so this part just return: <div="aa"></div>
<div id="send">apple</div>
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo '<div id="aa">';
//'.$_REQUEST['value'].' will put in some process here, but sometimes the return data is empty.
echo '</div>';
?>
```

How and where do I add a judgement, if `<div id="aa"></div>` is empty, add `sorry, there is no result` between it

so in `a.php`, the imformation will show: `<div id="result"><div id="aa">sorry, there is no result</div></div>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your AJAX call to be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
var params = "value=" + $('#send').text();   
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'html',            
     data:params,  
     success:function(data){  
         $("#result").html($(data).html('#aa'));
        if ( $("#aa").html() == "" ) {
            $("#aa").html("sorry, there is no result");
       }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This is not correct, `html` does not accept a jQuery object (at least according to the docs).

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should **always** return DATA / INFORMATION, not HTML Tags or code... that, you do in the HTML part.

```
<?php
//send ONLY the data, best to send in JSON syntax
?>
```

and then you use

```
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'html',            
     data:params,  
     success: function(data) {  

         if(data.length == 0)
             $("#result").html("<span class='no-data'>No Data</span>"); 
         else
         {
             // Loop through the data and add it as, for example an <li> in a <ul>
         }

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$("#result").html($(data).html('#aa'));
```

is not correct. It will set the content of the element contained in `data` to `#aa`.

I think you want:

```
function(data){  
    var $data = $(data);

    $data.html(function(i, html) {
        if(html === '') {
            return "sorry, there is no result";
        }
        return html;
    );

    $("#result").empty().append($data);
}
```

---

But wouldn't it be easier, to just return the result text instead of returning HTML?

So in PHP:

```
<?php
    echo getResultOfYourProcess();
?>
```

and on the client side:

```
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'text',            
     data:params,  
     success:function(data){
         data = data === '' ? "sorry, there is no result" : data;
         $("#result").html(data); 
         // or $("#result").text(data); 
     }
});
```